# How to use a psql variable in the middle of other characters?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I was wondering if it was possible to use a variable in the middle of other characters in an SQL statement with psql.

For example:

```
psql -v x=apple -f "example.sql"
```

with example.sql being:

```
SELECT * FROM :x;
```

Works fine. It's executed as:

```
SELECT * FROM apple;
```

but how do I handle a situation where example.sql is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM red_:x_pie;
```

I want psql to read it as "red_apple_pie" but I get a syntax error on ":" instead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use string concatenation:

```
DECLARE
x TEXT;

BEGIN
x = 'apple';

SELECT *
FROM "Food"
WHERE "Name" = 'red_' || x || '_pie';
```

I used this example because it's simpler to understand (table names have to be enclosed in quotes).

Answer (score 0):

```
\set table_x 'red_' :x '_pie'

SELECT * FROM :table_x;
```